# How do I wait for a random amount of milliseconds in batch with the ping command?

Tags: batch-file, random, wait, ping

```
set /a wait=%RANDOM% * 250 / 32768
echo %wait%
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %wait% >nul
[execute code, then go back to the beginning]
```

That's my code, which is in a loop.
It's supposed to wait for a random amount of milliseconds from 0 to 250, using the ping -w parameter.
I used the echo to see if it was actually random each time. It was. However, the actual wait time was not. It kept executing the code at a steady rate, rather than the random amount I was looking for.

Comment: note that `wait` will never be 250 because the maximum value for `%ramdom%` is 32767

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc If you would actually look at my code, then i have set the "wait" variable to %RANDOM% * 250 / 32768

Comment: if you read my comment then that's what exactly I'm talking about. `%RANDOM% * 250 / 32768` will return a value from 0-249, not 250